# How/where is the working directory of a program stored?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, filesystems, d, thread-local

When a program accesses files, uses `system()`, etc., how and where is the current working directory of that program physically known/stored?  Since logically the working directory of a program is similar to a global variable, it should ideally be thread-local, especially in languages like D where "global" variables are thread-local by default.  Would it be possible to make the current working directory of a program thread-local?

Note:  If you are not familiar with D specifically, even a language-agnostic answer would be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Current directory is maintained by the OS, not by language or framework. See [description of GetCurrentDirectory WinAPI function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364934%28VS.85%29.aspx) for details.

From description:

> Multithreaded applications and shared
>   library code should not use the
>   GetCurrentDirectory function and
>   should avoid using relative path
>   names. The current directory state
>   written by the SetCurrentDirectory 
>   function is stored as a global
>   variable in each process, therefore
>   multithreaded applications cannot
>   reliably use this value without
>   possible data corruption from other
>   threads that may also be reading or
>   setting this value.

Comment: +1: Also the OS isn't even required to *have* a current directory. Or even have directories at all. The 'filesystem' could be a key/value DB that lets you put colons, slashes and back-slashes in the keys just for the fun of it but does not actually care.

Answer (score 13):

On Linux, each process is represented by a process descriptor - a `task_struct`. This structure is defined in [include/linux/sched.h](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/sched.h;h=1e2a6db2d7dd03466bf850dc5011860c23e8f9c9;hb=HEAD) in the kernel source.

One of the fields of `task_struct` is a pointer to an `fs_struct`, which stores filesystem-related information. `fs_struct` is defined in [include/linux/fs_struct.h](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/fs_struct.h;h=a42b5bf02f8bcfec3ea20ecef765df3f4d690250;hb=HEAD).

`fs_struct` has a field called `pwd`, which stores information about the current working directory (the filesystem it is on, and the details of the directory itself).

Comment: `pwd` is of type [`struct path`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/path.h), which is basically a pair of `vfsmount-dentry`. [`dentry`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/dcache.h) has a field of type `struct inode *d_inode`, which uniquely identifies a file within its file system, and [`vfsmount`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/include/linux/mount.h) can represent a file system, so these two fields together can locate a file. Is this true?